# Uploading files to a domain using form

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, document-root

I have written an application in CakePHP 3.x and there is a form to upload files.

At present, files are being uploaded to `WWW_ROOT.'files'` which is `/app/webroot/files/` path.

To store files separately from core application, I created a subdomain `cdn.example.com` whose path is like `/home/user/example.com/cdn.example.com/`.

since, uploading files requires absolute path, how can I get absolute path of the subdomain `cdn.example.com` same as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` from `example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your server allow to write files from main domain to subdomain.

You can't get the absolute path of a different domain of the one you deployed your application, you should store the path in a variable or in constant.

If you really need to store files in another domain/subdomain and any path is blocked you should consider to reupload the files via FTP script.